# Printing NP chunked words

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to extract NP chunks from a text file.I have done it.But I want to print those NP chunked words alone.How can I do it.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
file =open("l2.txt","r")
text=file.read()
tokenized_words = word_tokenize(text)
pos_list=nltk.pos_tag(tokenized_words)
grammar = "NP : {<JJ|JJR|JJS> *(<NNP> + <POS> *)?<NN|NNS|NNP|NNPS>+}"
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse(pos_list)
print(result)
```

This is my code.I want the output like
NP words: followed by the words and not the entire output with other tags.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines at the end of your code should do the trick:

```
for r in result:
    if type(r) == nltk.tree.Tree:
        if r.label() == 'NP':
            print('NP:', ' '.join([x[0] for x in r.leaves()]))
```